# How can I use 2 forms in the same controller on a symfony project?

Tags: symfony, controller, symfony-forms

I want to use 2 forms, one primary and  an other secundary, in the same controller 'new_data' on my symfony project. I want to stay on the same page when I submit the secundary form. The primary form should redirect to the index page, but the secundary should add data in a list which as to be submitted only when the user submit the first form.

I have changed the instruction : redirect.... into commentary. And so the result is an error message because the form is not submitted.

The aim of that is that the secundary form add data in a list and when the user is ready, he validates the process by submitting the primary form.

If someone could help me I would be very gratefull.

Here is the code of my controller :

```
public function new(Request $request, ArmyRepository $armyRepository, RegionRepository $regionRepository, NotificationRepository $notificationRepository): Response
{
    $army = new Army();
    $form = $this->createForm(ArmyType::class, $army);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form2 = $this->createForm(SelectCUType::class, $army);
    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    $notifmenu = $notificationRepository->findBy(['statut'=>'non lu','addressee'=>$this->getUser()]);
    $regions = $regionRepository->findAll();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $armyRepository->add($army, true);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_army_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $armyRepository->add($army, true);

        //return $this->redirectToRoute('app_army_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('army/new.html.twig', [
        'army' => $army,
        'form2' => $form2,
        'form' => $form,
        'regions' => $regions,
        'user' => $user,
        'notifmenu'=>$notifmenu,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You need to somehow remember that the first form has already been sent and query it accordingly: `if (!$form1sent && $form->isSubmitted()) {}`. You can do this with a GET or POST parameter or use the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you process the secondary form then the primary is not anymore to find inside the new function because the item is created by the secondary form or lets say it needs to be created

you can implement a button inside your form type (and the twig file) to call the new() function on the secondary controller. this process should be creates the primary item, so you can add secondary items to the primary item and redirect after creating the secondary stuff to the edit() function of the primary item like this, but you need to fill the required data columns like placeholders of your primary item

```
// src/Controller/PrimaryController.php
public function new(Request $request, ArmyRepository $armyRepository, RegionRepository $regionRepository, NotificationRepository $notificationRepository): Response
{
    $army = new Army();
    $form = $this->createForm(ArmyType::class, $army);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $notifmenu = $notificationRepository->findBy(['statut'=>'non lu','addressee'=>$this->getUser()]);
    $regions = $regionRepository->findAll();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $armyRepository->add($army, true);
        
        // new secondary item
        /** @var SubmitType $btnAddSecondaryStuff */
        $btnAddSecondaryStuff = $form->get('secondary_stuff_add_btn');

        if ($btnAddSecondaryStuff->isClicked()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('secondary_stuff_add_route', ['id' => $army->getId()], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_army_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('army/new.html.twig', [
        'army' => $army,
        'form' => $form,
        'regions' => $regions,
        'user' => $user,
        'notifmenu'=>$notifmenu,
    ]);
}
```

add the add button to the edit function too

```
// src/Controller/PrimaryController.php
public function edit(Request $request, Army $army, ArmyRepository $armyRepository, RegionRepository $regionRepository, NotificationRepository $notificationRepository): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ArmyType::class, $army);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $notifmenu = $notificationRepository->findBy(['statut'=>'non lu','addressee'=>$this->getUser()]);
    $regions = $regionRepository->findAll();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $armyRepository->add($army, true);

        // new secondary item
        /** @var SubmitType $btnAddSecondaryStuff */
        $btnAddSecondaryStuff = $form->get('secondary_stuff_add_btn');

        if ($btnAddSecondaryStuff->isClicked()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('secondary_stuff_add_route', ['id' => $army->getId()], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        // regular save
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_army_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    $secondaryItems = $army->getSecondaryItems();

    return $this->renderForm('army/edit.html.twig', [
        'army' => $army,
        'secondary_items' => $secondaryItems,
        'form' => $form,
        'regions' => $regions,
        'user' => $user,
        'notifmenu'=>$notifmenu,
    ]);
}
```

inside your form type you need to add the add button

```
// src/Form/PrimaryFormType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('secondary_stuff_add_btn', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'add secondary item',
        ])
    ;
}
```

inside your twig file you can drop a list of existing secondary items and add the add button

```
// templates/army/_form.html.twig
{{ form_row(form.secondary_stuff_add_btn) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly works except the last or your instruction :

Comment: the twig implementation ? depent on how you set the form inside your twig file, can be different in some situations